# Javascript/JQuery - Change background color of HTML table cells before and after cell with a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to change HTML table cells before and after I find a cell with a value of 76.  The cells before and after are string values.  I was able to get the whole row to change background color based on the one cell value, but not what I want.

```
var r = $(this).data('row');
if(/76/.test(r.where.m_cur_state_id) && timeInOper >= 0){
$(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
$(this).children().css('color','#FFF');         
}
```

Any direction on how to make the cell with value of 76 red and the cell before and after red?

Comment: it would be better to push the data to an attrib on the cell, then you can use CSS to hit specific cells, adjacent cells, adjacent+n cells, etc, all really fast and without brittle JS. `<td data-val=76>76</td>`  `td[data-val='76'] { color: red; } td[data-val='76']+td { color: pink; }`

Answer (score 1):

See the jQuery `.prev()` and `.next()` functions.

- https://api.jquery.com/prev/
- https://api.jquery.com/next/